# How should I handle this hydration error?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, hydration

I have a "use client" component that throws hydration errors:

2x `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

1x `There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.`

This is the component:

```
export default function NavigationButton(props: NavigationButtonProps) {
  const isInDesktopClient = useDesktopClient((state) => state.isInDesktopClient);

  return isInDesktopClient ? (
    <Button
      {...props}
      variant={props.variant}
      onClick={() => {
        desktopClientPlugin.openInWorkspace(
          `${window.location.origin}/${props.href}`,
          props.title || "",
          props.subTitle,
        );
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  ) : (
    <Button
      {...props}
      component={Link}
      href={props.href}
      variant={props.variant}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

It is supposed to render a button that either navigates you to a new url if you are in a regular browser. But if you are in the embedded browser of a desktop client, it should render a button that opens said url in a new "workspace" in the desktop client.

The `isInDesktopClient` is zustand-state that is set in a component loaded in the head of the application like so:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <ColorSchemeScript />
        <DesktopClient />
      </head>
      <body className={`${circularFont.className} bg-neutral-20`}>
        <TRPCProvider>
          <MantineProviders>{children}</MantineProviders>
        </TRPCProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

This is the `DesktopClient` component, it waits for the desktopPlugin(that lets the embedded browser and the desktop client communicate) to be setup. If it responds it stores the ticket in cookies and sets the zustand-state to true for later use:

```
export default function DesktopClient() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchClientTicket = () => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (desktopClientPlugin.isReady()) {
          clearInterval(interval);

          const clientTicket = desktopClientPlugin.getTicket();
          Cookies.set("clientTicket ", clientTicket || "");
          useDesktopClient.setState({ isInDesktopClient: true });
        }
      }, 100);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    };
    fetchClientTicket();
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

The "isInDesktopClient" is obviously never true on the server, so the server-rendered html will never match what is in the embeddedbrowser within the desktop client.

How can I do this in a way that doesnt cause hydration errors?

Comment: Found a solution. Disabling SSR for components that needs to check if is in the desktop client or not.
`
dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NavigationButton), { 
    ssr: false 
})
`